# Is there something wrong with the way I am using sets in python?

Tags: python, string, set

I want to use sets to check for anagram, and I think I am doing it correctly. First I add all elements of string A to the set and then returning a flag based on elements of string B.

```
def return_anagram(a, b):

    flag = True
    test_set = set()
    
    for char in a:
        test_set.add(char)

    for char in b:

        if b not in test_set:
            flag = False
            break

    return flag


print(return_anagram("abc", "cba"))
```

but it doesn't work for some reason, it returns false even though the elements are clearly matching. Anyone know the issue?

Comment: btw, *no need to loop and add*, just `test_set = set(a)`

Comment: in any case, look at this line, think about what this is doing: `if b not in test_set:`

Comment: Also, you should use built-in set operations for this. Note, a `set` is not the correct thing to use if your inputs have duplicate letters (which the name implies that they might. In that case, you want to use a *multiset*, which is implemented in `collections.Counter`, in which case, this just becomes `return Counter(b) == Counter(b)`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Voting to close as a typo. Think carefully about the code `if b not in test_set:`. What is the thing that you want to look for `in test_set`: the entire `b` string, or one of the letters? What is the name that the code uses for "one of the letters"? (Hint: what does `for char in b:` mean?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just needed to change the order of your code, you should be using `char` in each loop not `b`. So `if char not in` instead of what you have here.

Also, you can instantly create a set using `set(a)`.

```
def return_anagram(a, b):

    flag = True
    test_set = set(a) # instantiate your set here

    for char in b:

        if char not in test_set: #change this part to char instead of b
            flag = False
            break

    return flag


print(return_anagram("abc", "cba"))
```

My output is `True`.

As the comment below mentioned, you could also do,

```
def return_anagram(a, b):
    return set(a) == set(b)

print(return_anagram("abc", "cba"))
```

You will also get `True`.

However, you might want to rethink using sets and using a different data structure, because the words `abbc` and `bcca` will return `True` as sets will remove the duplicate characters.

As, suggested in the comments, instead of using a list or sets, you should use a multiset as the data structure has already been implemented.

Below I have made 2 implementations, one using the multiset module which you have to install, and the next using the Counter module from the built-in standard python library.

Option1:
First install the module by using `pip install multiset`.

Next all you have to do is import it and replace `set` with `Multiset` like this.

```
from multiset import Multiset
def return_anagram(a, b):
    return Multiset(a) == Multiset(b)
```

Option2:
You could also use the built in `Counter` tool from the standard `collections` library.

```
from collections import Counter

def multiset(array):
    return set(Counter(array).items())

def return_anagram(a, b):
    return multiset(a) == multiset(b)
```

Now,

```
print(return_anagram("bca", "abc"))
```

returns `True`,

while,

```
print(return_anagram("abbc", "ccba"))
```

returns, `False` with both codes.

Comment: note, this could just be `return set(a) == set(b)`

Comment: yeah you're right

Comment: Thanks a lot, also the two strings being passed into the anagram function are the same length so that isn't an issue

Comment: @PranavNarayan what about repeat characters? Like 'accb' and 'aacb' this would come out as true as well

Comment: "and using lists of characters instead" *no*. Don't use lists. Use a *multiset* (i.e. a dict of counts)

Comment: @PranavNarayan it *will* matter. I warned you about this in a comment above

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga i added the multiset example.

Comment: @anarchy **no**. For starters, that isn'ta part of the standard library. Just use `collections.Counter`

Comment: also, `from multiset import *` is a very, very bad practice

Comment: ah i know about the counter as well ill add an example later